# How to get the color beneath an opaque JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, opacity, getcolor

Is there is a way to get the color underneath an opaque `JPanel`?

I have two `JPanel`s, a red one and a blue one (they are animated). I want to get the color of a surface according to the `JPanel` that passes over it.

In following images, the small borderd square is an opaque `JPanel`, and I want to retrieve the color of the `JPanel` beneath.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/45YQV.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXKmN.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you are asking. But assuming you know the x/y location of the rectangle you could use:

1. The `getComponentAt(...)` method of the `Container` class. Once you get the parent panel you use the getBackground()` method to get the Color
2. Or, you can use the `Robot class and the` getPixelColor(...)` method.

Comment: Thank youuu sooo much !! just tried the first getcomponentat and it worked ! thanks again !